# grep specific value to use as filename from data using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file with data as below

```
 * sub : A
  111
 ------------------
 * sub : B
  222
 -------------------
 * sub : C
 333
 --------------------
```

I have to separate this data into 3 different files based on end of value "-----------------".
I have written code to separate file.

But , Now I have to take out the value name written after "sub : " like A, B,C and use it in output filename.

Code I written below:

```
cat SAMP.txt | awk 'BEGIN{RS="-----+";i=1} {print $0>i".sql"}{i++}'
```

How can I modify this to grep value from sub and use it in i and make the file name as A.sql , B.sql and C.sql .

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is what you want...

```
$ awk -v RS='-----+' '{print > ($4".sql")}' file
```

perhaps more robust with these changes

```
$ awk -F: 'NF>1 && !f {f=$NF".sql"} 
           /------+$/ {close(f); f=""; next} 
                      {print > f}' file
```

produces

```
$ head *.sql
==>  A.sql <==
 * sub : A
  111

==>  B.sql <==
 * sub : B
  222

==>  C.sql <==
 * sub : C
 333
```

Comment: is it possible to write a regex after begin to search a pattern and then save its value to a variable to use it further something like : awk '/sub/{sub(/* sub : /,""); print}' ,

Comment: variable in pattern not supported but you can write it as `$0~var{do something}`

Comment: this one not working :( it should have created 3 files but created only 1 A.sql with all the data

Comment: did you test with the sample input file posted above?

Comment: The first script will only work with gawk for multi-char RS, other awks will treat it as if RS was just the single char `-`. The 2nd one will create output file names that start with a blank (change the FS to `<blank>:<blank>` or similar to fix that) but **will** do what the OP asked for.

Answer (score -1):

A different way to do this,

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="-----+";i=1} {print $0>i".sql"}{i++}'
for i in *.sql ; do name=$(sed -n 's/.*sub : \(.*\)/\1/p' $i) ; if [[ ! -z "$name" ]] ; then mv "$i" "${name}.sql" ; fi ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It is fixed (except the multiple commands part)